# Complex WHERE expression using CASE-THEN in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query:

```
SELECT ID FROM requests WHERE date <operator> <expression>
```

I need to change `<expression>` relying on my stored procedure's parameter.

If flag is set: `WHERE date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE()`

If is not: `WHERE date = date`

I tried to use CASE-THEN but it forces using concrete operator but I have to have few:

```
SELECT ID FROM requests WHERE date = -- here it is
CASE
  WHEN @flag = 1 THEN ..
  ELSE date
END
```

Comment: How about SELECT ID FROM requests WHERE CASE WHEN @flag = 1 THEN date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE() ELSE 1 = 1 END?

Comment: @shahkalpesh could you please post it as an answer with highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    id
from
    requests
where
    (
        flag = 1
        and
        date between getdate()-7 and getdate()
    )
    or
    (
        flag <> 1
        and
        date = date
    )
```

Comment: @kurosch: good use of OR. One can exclude the date = date when flag <> 1.

Comment: @Remus: Thats a new buzzword "unsargable". Looked it up on wikipedia. "sargable" = search argument to facilitate use of index. I understand what you mean by "unsargable", now.

Comment: @Remus: if @flag is 1, the index on the [poorly named] date column (assuming one exists) would be used - no?

Comment: @rexem: the query optimizer may end up choosing a plan that satisfief *both* conditions `date between...` *and* `date=date` and decide to do a scan. While in this case you *may* get away with the `OR`, the proper thing to do in such situations is always to check the @flag in an ordinary IF and have separate queries on each branch so the optimizer knows exactly  what you want in each case.

Comment: I'm actually an Oracle person, I know nothing about sqlserver to tsql

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID FROM requests WHERE 
    (date = date and @flag <> 1 ) 
    or ( date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE() and @flag = 1)
```

Or in the Transact-SQL

```
if @flag = 1
    then
     SELECT ID FROM requests WHERE date = date
    else
     SELECT ID FROM requests WHERE date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it using the good old IF statement

```
if @flag = 1
   SELECT ID FROM requests WHERE date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE()
else
   SELECT ID FROM requests
```

EDIT: I am not sure if it works. But, here is what I added in the comment

```
SELECT ID FROM requests 
WHERE 
CASE WHEN @flag = 1 THEN date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE() 
ELSE 1 = 1 
END
```

EDIT2: I think it makes sense to use IF statement (if it is in TSQL). Because, the condition relies on external variable other than something from the row

i.e. CASE will do a comparison of @flag for each of the row, which is not needed.

Comment: The CASE in the WHERE clause won't work, or it fails for me on SQL Server 2005 with 'Incorrect syntax ner the keyword BETWEEN'.

Comment: @rexem: I do not have SQL server handy to try things. I guess that could be due to DATE as the name of the field?

Comment: @Shak: No, I was testing with a datetime column called "created".  I'm not using 2008, but it's in line with the OPs comments about not getting it to work.

Comment: The second code scope doesn't work too on my SQL 2008 Express

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, you can't use a CASE statement in the WHERE clause.  Your alternatives are:

Option 1: WHERE clause

```
SELECT t.id 
  FROM REQUESTS t
 WHERE 1 = 1
    OR (@flag = 1 AND t.date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE())
```

Option 2: Use IF and have two (or more depending on situation) distinct SQL statements

```
IF @flag = 1
   SELECT t.id 
     FROM REQUESTS t
ELSE
   SELECT t.id 
     FROM REQUESTS t
    WHERE t.date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE())
```

Option 3: dynamic SQL (Everyone's favorite)

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar (4000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT t.id 
              FROM REQUESTS t 
             WHERE 1 = 1'

IF @flag = 1 
  SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND t.date BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Personally, I loath to deal with Option 2.  Near identical statements make me want to refactor into a single SQL query.  That said, use #1 if things aren't too complex.  Otherwise, use dynamic.

Comment: could you please describe what for are you using 1=1 in option1 ? Unfortunately option2 isn't applicable for my case because original query is much-much bigger then in my OP. I don't trust (yet, maybe) to optimization of dynamic SQL so prefer to use pure t-sql

Comment: I had to use the 1 = 1 in Option 1 because no data would return if the flag != 1.  It's habit for me to use it in dynamic SQL in case I need to append to the WHERE clause.  It's better than using t.date = t.date because that'd use an index for a situation that would always be true.